# Content ingestion and properties update using marklogic dls API in same transaction

Tags: transactions, xquery, marklogic

```
import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

let $uri := "/ml-workflow/test2.xml" 

let $content := <apple>APPLE</apple>

let $properties := <prop>MANGO</prop>

return

(dls:document-insert-and-manage($uri,fn:false(),$content),dls:document-set-properties($uri,$properties) )
```

Question: I am trying to insert a document and set its properties using Marklogic dls API in the same transaction, but it is not allowing me to do so.
Kindly help!

Comment: If you're getting a conflicting updates error, the short answer is you can't. But you can use a multi-statement transaction (MST) to effectively do both in separate transactions, but commit them simultaneously. http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_19551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained with code samples at http://blakeley.com/blogofile/2013/06/21/introduction-to-multi-statement-transactions/

Try something like this:

```
import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls"
  at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

declare option xdmp:transaction-mode "update";

let $uri := "/ml-workflow/test2.xml" 
let $content := <apple>APPLE</apple>
return dls:document-insert-and-manage($uri,fn:false(),$content)
;

import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls"
  at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

let $uri := "/ml-workflow/test2.xml" 
let $properties := <prop>MANGO</prop>
return dls:document-set-properties($uri,$properties)
xdmp:commit()
```

If you use external variables you can avoid the repeated values.